# PHP: How to insert array value into mysql statement

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i have this array and get it from from an url. this array is member id that i need to pass to mysql.

```
$member_id = $_GET['member_id'];
```

the array like this : `Array ( [0] => 1269 [1] => 385 )`

how can i **transfer this array into my mysql** statement and make , become AND :

```
$answer_sql = mysql_query("SELECT tna_category. * , tna_question. *, tna_answer. * 
                        FROM tna_category, tna_question, tna_answer 
                        WHERE  tna_category.section_id = '$section_id1' 
                        AND tna_question.id = tna_answer.question_id AND tna_question.category_id = tna_category.id 
                        AND tna_answer.member_id = ['1269' , '385']
                        ORDER BY tna_answer.question_id");
```

should i put bracket?..

in this part  : **tna_answer.member_id = Array or $member_id**

Comment: get teh array value by foreach and  pass the  query in foreach

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: how can i do foreach in Mysql. sorry can you teach me more.

Comment: Also, try `tna_answer_member_id IN (1269, 385)`. See [`IN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)

Comment: i thought to that also. IN . thanks Phil

Comment: Check my(@user2727841) answer its tested!!!

Comment: wait... i will test all of you guys answers... i do not know why intelligent people like to downgrade questions and answer. If they do not know just ignore my question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP PDO: Can I bind an array to an IN() condition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition)

Comment: for my case i not using PDO

Comment: @airi You can apply the same logic to MySQLi

Comment: @airi you can also use `mysql_real_escape_string` function like this `$member_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['member_id']);` and then explode it just I did... check it here about `mysql_real_escape_string` `www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: check member id like `$member_id = explode(",", $member_id);` `print_r($member_id);` and tell me what are you getting...

Comment: i got error when use explode.. when i used implode it ok

Comment: If you are getting comma seprated value in `$_GET["member_id"];` don't use explode just use implode.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use `IN` clause of mysql like this

```
$your_array = array("0"=>"1269", "1"=>"385");


 $in_text = implode(",", $your_array);

   $sql = "SELECT tna_category. * , tna_question. *, tna_answer. * 
        FROM tna_category, tna_question, tna_answer 
        WHERE  tna_category.section_id = '$section_id1' 
               AND tna_question.id = tna_answer.question_id 
               AND tna_question.category_id = tna_category.id  
               AND tna_answer.member_id IN ($in_text)
               ORDER BY tna_answer.question_id";
```

Comment: well.. this is offline website not online and it only used by one administrator.. cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you can use `IN()` but you are apparently open to SQL injection attacks as it is. You need to do this:

```
$escaped_ids = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $member_ids);
```

Or, if they are surely all integers

```
$escaped_ids = array_map('intval', $member_ids);
```

Then, you can write your query like:

```
$query = "SELECT tna_category. * , tna_question. *, tna_answer. * 
          FROM tna_category, tna_question, tna_answer 
          WHERE  tna_category.section_id = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($section_id1) . "' 
              AND tna_question.id = tna_answer.question_id 
              AND tna_question.category_id = tna_category.id 
              AND tna_answer.member_id IN (".implode(",", $escaped_ids).")
          ORDER BY tna_answer.question_id";
```

Never, never, never put unescaped values in your query.

Also, you should not be using the `mysql_` functions anymore. Please consider using the `mysqli_` functions instead.

Comment: Might as well sanitise `$section_id1` too

Comment: Thanks, @Phil, I didn't notice it!

Answer (score 1):

First split the array value, get no. of rows in the array value and pass the value one by one into the query by using for or foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$member_id = $_GET['member_id'];
```

If you're already getting comma seprated values then there's no need to use `explode` function just use `implode` function in database query.

```
$member_id = explode(",", $member_id);
```

and then

```
answer_sql = mysql_query("SELECT tna_category. * , tna_question. *, tna_answer. * 
                        FROM tna_category, tna_question, tna_answer 
                        WHERE  tna_category.section_id = '$section_id1' 
                        AND tna_question.id = tna_answer.question_id AND tna_question.category_id = tna_category.id 
                        AND tna_answer.member_id IN (".implode(",", $member_id).")
                        ORDER BY tna_answer.question_id");
```

the `explode` function create array it depends on you `explode` value with comma OR space and then implode mean join these values with comma OR space.
for more detail [explode](http://pk1.php.net/explode) and [implode](http://pk1.php.net/function.implode).

Comment: Considering the `member_id` array comes from external input, this is very unsafe

Comment: PDO or MySQLi, prepared statements and parameter binding. It's really the **only** safe way

Comment: Yet another reason **not** to use them

Comment: @Phil have you seen. OP using `mysql_query` so don't try to demotivate anyone else

Comment: @Phil you will protect them from mysql injection am i right?

Comment: @SatishSharma I'm in fact attempting to do the opposite; I'm trying to **motivate** people to stop using deprecated and unsafe libraries.

Comment: @SatishSharma I don't have to. It's already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition)

Comment: Thanks to Satish Sharma and Phil I also learn here one more new thing thanks for all of you!!!

Comment: i got this : Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Comment: You learnt a **new** thing?! This stuff has been around for almost 10 years! There's been a large banner on all the `mysql_*` functions recommending you use MySQLi or PDO for 10 years!